# Extracting Experience Section from resume

Tags: python, regex

Below is the Code to extract the Experience section from the Resume , but its not giving the desired output :

```
import re

def extract_experience(resume_text):
    experience_pattern = r"(?:EXPERIENCE|Employment experience)\n(.*?)\n(?:Skills|Education)"
    experience_match = re.search(experience_pattern, resume_text, re.DOTALL)

    # Extract the Experience section from the match
    if experience_match:
        experience_section = experience_match.group(1)
        return experience_section
    else:
        return "Experience section not found"
```

Below is my text that i have converted from pdf using `PyPDF2`

```
resume_text = 

xyz  
66 Chetwynd Road 
UK  
  
Phone - 070040040040  
Email - a18@hotmail.co.uk  
PERSONAL PROFILE  
I am an energetic, hardworking individual who has developed a responsible approach to any 
task I undertake or problem I’m presented with. With previous experience in both customer 
service and administration, I can skillfully work with others and help with situations I am 
faced with in a calm collective manner.  
EXPERIENCE  
Play Centre  
HOST (September 2021- Present)   
▪ Working well under pressure, making decisions quickly and strategically  
▪ Problem -solving and using initiative  
 
xyz center  
Sales Assistant (November 2020 -January 2020)  
▪ Interacted with customers ensuring service was welcoming and helpful.  
▪ Responded to any queries   
 
 
Health & Wellness Club - Work Experience   
Staff - (January 2020 - February 2020)  
▪ Welcomed members into the gym  
▪ Ensured all equipment was safe and clean before it was used by members  
  
EDUCATION   
September 2021 -2022 
University College
```

It always gives the output as `Experience section not found`

**Expected Output i am looking for :**

```
Play Centre  
HOST (September 2021- Present)

xyz center  
Sales Assistant (November 2020 -January 2020)

Health & Wellness Club - Work Experience   
Staff - (January 2020 - February 2020)
```

what am i missing.?
Also is there any other effective way to extract the same. plz guide

Comment: There is no newline after EXPERIENCE, remove it, or replace with `\s*`. Also, there is `EDUCATION`, not `education`. `(?:EXPERIENCE|Employment experience)\s*(\S.*?)\s*(?:Skills|EDUCATION)` might be what you need. Or `(?i:EXPERIENCE|Employment experience)\s*(\S.*?)\s*(?i:Skills|EDUCATION)`. Or even `(?m)^(?:EXPERIENCE|Employment experience)\s*(\S.*?)\n(?:Skills|EDUCATION)`

Comment: And try using a case insensitive match https://regex101.com/r/IvtnsE/1

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew
 what if we only want the heading of each experienc.?

Comment: Please explain what you need to get as a result in the question.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew    Play Centre  
HOST (September 2021- Present)   , xyz center  
Sales Assistant (November 2020 -January 2020) , Health & Wellness Club - Work Experience   
Staff - (January 2020 - February 2020)   i am looking to fetch this kind kind of info

Comment: made the edits in the question

Comment: Try [this approach](https://ideone.com/eGDJfI).

Comment: To match only the headers (in a horribly inefficient way) using only one expression, you could search for all lines that: do not precede `^(?:employment )?experience`, do precede `^education` and do not start with a bullet. Using lookaheads, this would give you something like `(?:^(?![\s\S]*?^(?:employment )?experience)[^▪].+\n){2,}(?=[\s\S]*?^education)`. See [expression demo](https://regex101.com/r/uytCOz/1). It would be better to remove everything up to the experience line and from the education line and then match for the headers in the remainder (multiple operations).

Answer (score -1):

How about this approach

```
"EXPERIENCE(.*)(?=EDUCATION)"s
```

https://regex101.com/r/mXlPIz/1

You could also use `(.*?)` instead of `(.*)`
The flag `s` is important as it will "tell" `.` to match newline as well.
This with the lookahead of `EDUCATION` gets us what we want